# Error connection refused cURL error 7 port 443

Tags: wordpress, security, updates

i have this error on Wordpress. "error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to api.wordpress.org port 443: Connection refused". How resolve this ?

I've modified my htaccess to make it more secure, and I've checked with my host to make sure everything's fine.